# PHP Mysqli query update not working with variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query:

```
$date = "january";
mysqli_query($connection->dbconn, "UPDATE monthly_visitors SET '$date' = 0");
```

But for some reason it does not work. The variable doesn't seem to work inside the query. Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: if you have more than the one row, well... that is a problem here and most likely why it is failing. Plus, `January` and `january` are two different animals, should that be the case. No idea what you want to do here though. Show us the db schema for this. You have a string and an integer. Columns don't use quotes, btw, they use backticks `\``

Comment: What does error reporting say? Are you sure `january` is the name of the column, not a value?

Comment: So what i'm trying to do is a simple "visitor counter", the database has 12 rows, which is january, february, mars, april, etc. Now the $date will be changed to display the current month with date(F), and strtolower to match my database rows. I only need it to update the the row which matches the current month, thats why I use the variable $date.

Comment: actually, your db won't entirely get updated (yet) because it never made it there in the first place. Why? Because, you have a major syntax error which is caused by the initial quote injection, but you didn't check for errors to start with; that's one of the faults with this. Here, see for yourself http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply that to your query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to set the value in a column called "january" to zero for all rows. Is that really what you want to do? If so then try to remove the quotes around "$date". It shouldn't be quoted because it's a column name.

Also, note that if $date would come from a user then this code snippet would be susceptible for SQL injections. Never use user input directly in a query. Verify it / escape it / use parameters instead.

Comment: [didn't I say that? Oh yeah, I did... just in a different way.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799414/php-mysqli-query-update-not-working-with-variable#comment64968946_38799414) *lol*

Comment: Right... sorry, I didn't notice :-/